# Angular4 - Services - Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

Tags: angular

I am trying to fetch data from the server and I got the following error:

Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403.

```
getGroupsResponse(): 
Observable<IMainPageGroupResponseModel> {
    this.dataUrl='http://localhost:8080/myApp/v1/Lookup/groups/list/19763';

    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers:headers });

    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl,options)
            .map((response:Response) => <IMainPageGroupResponseModel>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I have installed core plugin for chrome, my App is at port 4300 and server-side code is running locally at 8080 port.

I do not understand why I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your server side code. In order to request data from backend you need to implement the CORS headers. Specifically you need to allow origin from your frontend and you also need to allow the methods you support.